# Angular unable to register Service Worker if ScrollMagic Controller is created

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, gsap, scrollmagic

I want to enable service worker in my Angular powered website, but it doesn't register itself if scrollmagic is used. If I disable ScrollMagic controlled animations it registers just fine.

I imported GSAP, ScrollMagic in angular-cli.json:

```
      "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js",
    "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js",
    "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js"
  ]
```

and declaring in each component I use ScrollMagic:

```
declare let TimelineMax: any;
declare let ScrollMagic: any;
declare let TweenMax: any;
```

I create controller this way:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.animation();
}
 animation() {
    this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
      globalSceneOptions: {
        triggerHook: 'onLeave',
        duration: 0
      }
    });
    (...)
  }
}
```

So it registers service worker if I go to page that has no scrollmagic or I disable it onclick using:

```
(...)   
 this.controller.destroy();
(...)
```

In that case it loads SW when website is open (without refreshing).

It doesn't register SW if I use setTimeout or similar solutions to create controller:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
  globalSceneOptions: {
    triggerHook: 'onLeave',
    duration: 0
  }
});
}, 3000);
```

Edit:
SW config:
ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html"
      ],
      "versionedFiles": [
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }]
}
```

app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    (...)
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {enabled: environment.production})
  ],
```

Comment: Can you show your SW config as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#step-4-create-the-configuration-file-ngsw-configjson)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing same issue. Whenever you're using `setTimeout` or `setTimeInterval` function, that application can not get stabilize, that's why service workers are not being downloaded.

### Workaround :

Open `main.ts` and try to register service worker manually. It works for me.

```
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js'); // replace the file-name if you've changed
    }
  })
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

#### Reference Link :

https://github.com/ritwickdey/ritwickdey.github.io/blob/388d3d15e725b228ae80c0ae79beb5746c22cc8c/src/main.ts#L11
(This is my portfolio website project)

Comment: It works for me too. Thanks! 
Does it mean that scrollmagic causes app to be unstabilized all the time?